# Listings define language in a separate file

Tags: listings

I'm currently working on a paper where I want to showcase some JavaScript code snippets. I am using the `listing` package and defined JavaScript with `\lstdefinelanguage`.

Since the command with its numerous options is very long, I asked myself whether this could also be stored in a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be stored in a separate file, as in `\input{SubFolder/MyLanguageDefinition.tex}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.